# Elasticsearch: [filtered] query does not support [highlight]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have a filtered query as follows

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "term" : {
                    "title" : "crime"
                }
            },
            "highlight" : {
                "fields" : {
                    "title" : {}
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "year" : 1961 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried this query and got the error:

```
[filtered] query does not support [highlight]
```

Does filtered query support highlight? If not, how can I achieve highlight in query with filters? I have to use filters.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"highlight"` parameter should go at the same level as the `"query"` parameter, not embedded within it. In your case it should look something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "term" : {
                    "title" : "crime"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "year" : 1961 }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "title" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

- [Highlighting reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html)
- [Highlights problems with a filtered query](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Highlights-problems-with-a-filtered-query-td2679140.html)

Comment: Cool! Is it possible to highlight a field mentioned in filter/term instead or one in query/term? For example highlighting title if title and year swapped places in query?